# Command csvloop is already defined... How do I find the conflicting package?

Tags: csvsimple

In this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[slovene]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{acronym}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{mathpazo}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage[obeyspaces,spaces]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{code_linenumbers_b}{RGB}{215,215,215}
    \definecolor{code_linenumbers}{RGB}{255,255,255}
    \definecolor{code_background}{RGB}{240,240,240}
    \definecolor{code_comments}{RGB}{185,185,185}
    \definecolor{code_borders}{RGB}{7,161,226}
    \definecolor{code_keyword}{RGB}{0,0,0}
    \definecolor{headings}{RGB}{7,161,226}

\usepackage{menukeys}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage{titlesec}
    \titleformat*{\section}{\headingfont\Large\bfseries}
    \titleformat*{\subsection}{\headingfont\large\bfseries}
    \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\headingfont\normalsize\bfseries}

\usepackage[
    paperwidth=210mm,
    paperheight=297mm,
    top=3cm,
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    footskip=1cm,
    marginparsep=0cm,
    marginparwidth=0cm,
    headheight=1.7cm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rfoot{Stran \thepage}
    \lhead{Kicad \& Freecad interoperability for electronics}
    \rhead{...}

\usepackage{listings}
    \lstset{
        keepspaces=true,

        frame=l,
        captionpos=b,
        numbersep=3.5mm,
        xleftmargin=0.35cm,
        xrightmargin=0cm,
        framesep=0mm,
        framexleftmargin=2.5mm,
        framerule=0.5mm,

        rulecolor=\color{code_borders},
        fillcolor=\color{code_linenumbers_b},
        backgroundcolor=\color{code_background},

        basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{black},
        keywordstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{code_keyword},
        commentstyle=\ttfamily\itshape\color{code_comments},
        numberstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries\color{code_linenumbers},

        tabsize=3,
        breaklines=true,
        columns=fullflexible,
        showspaces=false,
        breakatwhitespace=true,
        breakautoindent=false
    }

\addto\captionsslovene{\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Datoteka}}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

If I keep thes package `\usepackage{csvsimple}` I get a warning at compilation time:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command '\csvloop ' is already defined.
```

But if I comment it out compilation suceeds.

And there is no hint whatsoever abaout which two packages might be colliding. Does anyone know which two? How do I solve this conflict?

Comment: I can't replicate your issue with [this minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/8auWUzgd). No error. Can you provide a minimal example that replicates your erroneous behaviour?

Comment: @Werner Ehh... Probably because I didn't paste all the code. Wait!

Comment: When I go to the error, it points to `catoptions` (part of `menukeys`). And sure enough, when you look at the bottom of the file [`catoptions.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/catoptions/tex/catoptions.sty) (on CTAN), it sets `\csvloop`. How do you resolve the conflict? It depends on what you want to do. Load either `menukeys` *or* `csvsimple`, but not both would be one solution.

Comment: @Werner. Do you think this could solve the issue? https://texfaq.org/FAQ-alreadydef

Comment: The fix in the link worked! I can have both packages.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, you can search for `\csvloop` in all the package files on your computer,
and you can also insert a bunch of `\show\cvsloop` in your document to see where it becomes defined. But here is a quick neat trick that should work. At the very beginning of you document put

```
\outer\def\csvloop{}
```

That should cause an error when something tries to define it (but it is not absolutely guaranteed).

(I never thought I'd see an actual good use of `\outer`.)